# Max-Width While Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I am using jQuery and am trying to implement the max-width property on my images that are being affected by jQuery but can't get it to work. Can anyone help me? Here is all of my coding:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    </head>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(window).load(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
    $('div.fade > div') . fadeIn(3000) // 3 second fade in
    }, 2000) // after 2 seconds.
    })
    </script>


    <style>
    .img{
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    html
    {
        background-image:url(purplegrad.png);
        background-position: center;
    }
    .container
    {
        position:relative;
        margin-top:100px;
    }
   .fade
   {
        position:relative;
        width:800px;
        z-index:1;
        margin:auto;
    }
    .inside 
    {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        z-index:2;
        top:0;
        left:0;
    }

  </style>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="fade">
                <img class="img" src="namelarge.png" />
                    <div class="inside">
                        <img class="img" src="nameglow.png" />
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

And here is an example of my jQuery in action that someone over on the jQuery forum helped me with: http://jsfiddle.net/jakecigar/HS2f9/

Comment: I don't see anything to do with max-width in your fiddle. What exactly is the problem? Is the dog picture supposed to fit in the smaller square?

Comment: It is there at the top of the styling in the coding I posted. Someone in another thread wanted to see how my jQuery works in a fiddle because it is probably causing the problem. When I put the max-width property in my styling for an image it won't work but when I take my jQuery out it does. Wherever I put max-width, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on what you are looking for, since you don't have max width in your example, but I believe you want:

```
.fade div img {
        max-width: 100%;
}
```

This will make sure your second image is set correctly.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/HS2f9/1/)

Comment: EDIT: Actually, I was looking at the wrong version of my coding - it just doesn't do anything at all, same as it is without it.

Comment: And the max-width is there in my CSS. This has nothing to do with the fiddle. It's just there to show what my jQuery does because I want the images affected by the jQuery also affected by max-width but it for some reason won't do both.